# Type 'Vector' is not defined

Tags: vb.net

I got error:

> Type 'Vector' is not defined.

I was using Visual Studio Community 2015, VB.NET, Framework 4.5.2.

And I got error on this line:

```
Dim vector1 As New Vector(40, 50)
```

Comment: Forms, WPF or Console?

Comment: Why do you think there should be a Vector type available to you?  There is the `System.Windows.Vector` structure but that is generally intended for use in WPF.  What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: @DavidSdot It was Forms.

Comment: By the way, I've never used that type. I simply opened the MSDN documentation and searched for "vector".  When I found that type I opened the topic and it showed what assembly the type is declared in and what namespace it's a member of.  You can do that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a Reference to **WindowsBase**

Import the Namespace

```
Imports System.Windows
```

Then it should work